# How to install python-fitbit module?

Tags: python, api, module, installation

I am following [this tutorial](https://roboticape.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/first-steps-into-the-quantified-self-getting-to-know-the-fitbit-api/) and try to download my personal Fitbit data. After cloning the [git repo](https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit), I don't know how to proceed.

Now if I run 'import fitbit', the error message shows:'No module named fitbit'. I think I am missing a 'installation' step. Can anyone tell me what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking to use the library, you don't need to clone the git repo at all. You should be able to just use `pip install fitbit`.

Comment: if above does not work,  try:   sudo pip install fitbit

Comment: @smarx, thanks! It worked fine, on both my Ubuntu and Windows10 machine. So I guess this applies to other modules too? Generally I don't need the repo and just need `pip install` them? Just in case I need another API module and same issue come to me again in the future.

Comment: Right. Generally `pip install` is how you install Python modules.